# XAML to change background opacity without changing color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my *C#* / *WPF* / *.NET 4.5* app I would like to implement a `Trigger` that toggles the background opacity of a control without changing its color.

Normally to set the background brush of a control, I would use the following `Setter`:

```
<Setter TargetName="TargetControl" Property="Background">
<Setter.Value>
  <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="0.2"/>
</Setter.Value>
```

Now I am in a situation where I have to change the opacity only and not the color. What would my setter look like in this case, where I don't care what color the background is but I want to preserve the color while changing the opacity?

#### More details:

The reason for this is that I am working on an `ItemsControl` where the background color changes depending on the item's `AlternationIndex`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" AlternationCount="6">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid x:Name="GridWithin">
      <!-- ... -->
      </Grid>
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <!-- Aternating colors for each row -->
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
          <Setter TargetName="GridWithin" Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="0.2"/>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
          <Setter TargetName="AllGesturesDataTemplateGrid" Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="Green" Opacity="0.2"/>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <!-- ... -->
        <!-- Highlight when a hit is registered -->
        <DataTrigger>
          <DataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsHit}" Value="True" />
          </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
          <!-- The culprit -->
          <Setter TargetName="GridWithin" Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
              <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.7"/>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
          <!-- /culprit -->
        </DataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It took me a little while to think of the best way to do this... it turns out that it was trickier than I had first thought. All the same, it is possible, but it does involve quite a lot of code. In order to be able to target the actual `Opacity` property of the `Background Brush` object, you'll need to use a `StoryBoard`... that's why this code example is so verbose.

Because we need to use a `Storyboard` object in the `DataTrigger`, that means that we must use the `DataTrigger.EnterActions` as a `Storyboard` cannot be used in the normal `DataTrigger.Setters` collection. This follows that we must also use the `DataTrigger.ExitActions` to provide another `Storyboard` that sets the `Opacity` property back to its original value. Try this:

```
<Grid Name="YourGrid">
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Green" Opacity="0.2" />
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=YourGrid}" 
                    Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Opacity)">
                                    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0.7" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Opacity)">
                                    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0.2" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

Despite the amount of code required to implement this method, it does do exactly what you were after. However, there is a simpler way to get the same overall effect, but with slightly less code. You *could* simply add a `Rectangle` into the back of each `Grid` cell, or division and set the colours and opacity on that instead. Using this method, you could simply set the `Rectangle.Opacity` value directly, although you would be using extra controls... the choice is yours.

Comment: I ended up using the `Rectangle` method =)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is almost identical to @Sheridans, but it saves a few lines of XAML (and there are always too many as it is...)

```
<Grid Name="YourGrid">
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Green" Opacity="0.2" />
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=YourGrid}" 
                    Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Opacity)">
                                <DoubleAnimation To="0.7" Duration="0" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Opacity)">
                                <DoubleAnimation To="0.2" Duration="0" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

Comment: +1 if only for the 'always too many as it is' note.

But also because it's worth recognition.

Answer (score -1):

"Grid" has its own "Opacity" property as well as a "Background" property.  Perhaps use your trigger to change that opacity and leave the background colour alone?

Comment: -1 Changing the `Grid.Opacity` will obviously make all of the contents see through as well... clearly not what was requested.

Comment: the "GridWithin" is the root of the template for a single item in the items control.

Comment: trigger off AlternatingIndex to set the background of that grid and trigger off IsHIt to set its opacity

Comment: *the "GridWithin" is the root of the template for a single item in the items control*... firstly, what makes you think that? It's certainly *not* shown in the question author's XAML. Secondly, even if it did contain just one control and you set the `Grid.Opacity` property, the single control would also be faded out and I'm pretty sure that was not the requirement.

Comment: firstly, the "GridWithin" is the root of the DataTemplate for the ItemsControl's ItemTemplate, so that does make it the "root" of a single itm

Comment: secondly, yeah your right, the opacity would be inherited to all the controls in the grid, not what is wanted, my bad

Comment: Listen... I down voted your answer because it was wrong, not because I wanted an argument. The aim was that you'd either correct it, or delete it, thereby increasing the usefulness of this website.

Comment: Also, as a new(ish) user, you may not know that any reputation points lost due to down votes will be 'refunded' when the down voted question is deleted... I'm just passing on some information here... don't bite my head off again.